# I need this code to use the Pi Camera and not a webcam

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, tracking

I am doing a ball tracking project and i found some sample code online that can get me started. This code uses a webcam to import the video but i will be using a go pro with the PiCamera port. I already have the adapter and have got the video working just by itself but when i try to switch this code around to work with it then i get errors everywhere.

Code:

```
# USAGE
# python ball_tracking.py --video ball_tracking_example.mp4
# python ball_tracking.py

# import the necessary packages
from collections import deque
from imutils.video import VideoStream
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2
import imutils
import time

# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-v", "--video",
    help="path to the (optional) video file")
ap.add_argument("-b", "--buffer", type=int, default=64,
    help="max buffer size")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# define the lower and upper boundaries of the "green"
# ball in the HSV color space, then initialize the
# list of tracked points
greenLower = (0, 100, 100)
greenUpper = (10, 255, 255)
pts = deque(maxlen=args["buffer"])

# if a video path was not supplied, grab the reference
# to the webcam
if not args.get("video", False):
    vs = VideoStream(src=0).start()

# otherwise, grab a reference to the video file
else:
    vs = cv2.VideoCapture(args["video"])

# allow the camera or video file to warm up
time.sleep(2.0)

# keep looping
while True:
    # grab the current frame
    frame = vs.read()

    # handle the frame from VideoCapture or VideoStream
    frame = frame[1] if args.get("video", False) else frame

    # if we are viewing a video and we did not grab a frame,
    # then we have reached the end of the video
    if frame is None:
        break

    # resize the frame, blur it, and convert it to the HSV
    # color space
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=600)
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame, (11, 11), 0)
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(blurred, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    # construct a mask for the color "green", then perform
    # a series of dilations and erosions to remove any small
    # blobs left in the mask
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, greenLower, greenUpper)
    mask = cv2.erode(mask, None, iterations=2)
    mask = cv2.dilate(mask, None, iterations=2)

    # find contours in the mask and initialize the current
    # (x, y) center of the ball
    cnts = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
        cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
    center = None

    # only proceed if at least one contour was found
    if len(cnts) > 0:
        # find the largest contour in the mask, then use
        # it to compute the minimum enclosing circle and
        # centroid
        c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
        ((x, y), radius) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
        M = cv2.moments(c)
        center = (int(M["m10"] / M["m00"]), int(M["m01"] / M["m00"]))

        # only proceed if the radius meets a minimum size
        if radius > 10:
            # draw the circle and centroid on the frame,
            # then update the list of tracked points
            cv2.circle(frame, (int(x), int(y)), int(radius),
                (0, 255, 255), 2)
            cv2.circle(frame, center, 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)

    # update the points queue
    pts.appendleft(center)

    # loop over the set of tracked points
    for i in range(1, len(pts)):
        # if either of the tracked points are None, ignore
        # them
        if pts[i - 1] is None or pts[i] is None:
            continue

        # otherwise, compute the thickness of the line and
        # draw the connecting lines
        thickness = int(np.sqrt(args["buffer"] / float(i + 1)) * 2.5)
        cv2.line(frame, pts[i - 1], pts[i], (0, 0, 255), thickness)

    # show the frame to our screen
    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    # if the 'q' key is pressed, stop the loop
    if key == ord("q"):
        break

# if we are not using a video file, stop the camera video stream
if not args.get("video", False):
    vs.stop()

# otherwise, release the camera
else:
    vs.release()

# close all windows
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

```
if not args.get("video", False):
vs = VideoStream(src=0).start()
```

This is were it takes video feed from webcam i believe

Comment: @nathancy In general, please don't copy code from off-site into posts on SE. Only the copyright holder has the right to re-publish and re-license the code. Please see [Pasting Fiddle snippet into original question as an edit](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344484/3773011) and [Edits that add OP's code from 3rd party site where the license is unavailable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348698/3773011). For pastebin.com, you may copy it, but you must include attribution, which is [a bit more complex](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356304/3773011) than most people assume, but not overly-complicated.

Comment: Thank you for letting me now. I was not aware of that. I initially thought moving the code off-site to SE would be beneficial for historical reasons since links eventually die and it would be better to embed the code in one place.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below Code.

```
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
import time
import cv2

# initialize the camera and grab a reference to the raw camera capture
camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (640, 480)
camera.framerate = 32
rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(640, 480))

# allow the camera to warmup
time.sleep(0.1)

# capture frames from the camera
for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):
    # grab the raw NumPy array representing the image, then initialize the timestamp
    # and occupied/unoccupied text
    image = frame.array
    cv2.rectangle(image,(150,70),(490,410),(0,255,0),3)
    # show the frame
    cv2.imshow("Frame", image)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    # clear the stream in preparation for the next frame
    rawCapture.truncate(0)

# if the `q` key was pressed, break from the loop
if key == ord("q"):
    break
```

You can also use Pi camera directly into Opencv

```
sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2
```

Load the drivers for the pi camera write this command every time you restart the Pi. 
Then You can use Pi camera similarly as you are using your Webcam.
Below code will also work

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```